# could not find module guard in storefront_controller

Tags: commerce-cloud, training, b2c

I get this error upon running newly created JHelloWorld.js:

> Cannot find module 'storefront_controllers/cartridge/scripts/guard'

I created this controller under training cartridge and following controller guide .

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't actually _run_ the JS for Commerce Cloud B2C locally. It is only intended to be executed on the hosted instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace storefront_controllers with Training_controllers

```
var guard = require('Training_controllers/cartridge/scripts/guard');
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved by putting locale address to require('c/users/.....) guard.js script